Moving a Skimmia
I have a Skimmia which is placed too close to the front of the border,
It is approximately 500mm tall. I want to move it back rather than removing it completely.
Can an established Skimmia be moved?

Why not lift it now and transplant the shrub? Are you worried about upsetting it close to blooming?

What part of the world are you in?

Why wouldn't it be? Do you need a summary of the tips for replanting? Part of world and urgency of the act would narrow it down too.
